# VSCode intellisense for Typescript Vue (Auto import at @Component)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vetur

I'm currently developing a small project in VSCode with Typescript and Vue.
I have VSCode with the following plugins TSLint, TSLint Vue, Vetur and Prettier.

I can not get the intellisense "auto import" part to work whenever i try and refer to a class from the @Component part like this.

```
@Component({
  components: {
    User //Here it doesn't work
  },
})
```

[Example of the error when trying to auto import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q15jk.png)

But as you can see here further down in the code it works.

```
import User from '@/models/user';

@Component({
  components: {
    User //Here it doesn't work
  },
})
export default class Project extends Vue {
  user: User = new User(); //Here i can get the intellisense to auto import "User"
}
```

[Example of the intellisense working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqRQv.png)

Is it because it's shorthanded and therefor can't reference it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i guess i'll just go with the solution without shorthand "User: user"